# Android Studio emulator crashed, now I can't start Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, out-of-memory

I accidentally ran my Android Studio project on an emulator (for a different device) instead of my real device (forgotten I unplugged it), and the whole computer froze/ran out of memory. No big deal I thought, I turned off my computer and started it again.

However, now when I start Android Studio, I run into problems. It first says `indexing` for a very long time (like 10 minutes+), then it goes to `Building symbols`  also for 10 minutes+, until it warns me about `low memory` and eventually runs out of memory.

The `out-of-memory` error window gave me the opportunity to increase the memory limit and I tried increase the memory field to 2000 (from 1200 something), and that is where I am now, still building symbols 20 minutes later. 
Edit: Now it ran out of memory again.

> Note that before, when I start Android Studio, everything was set up
>   within minutes

What should I do? Do I have to reinstall Android Studio? Should I change these memory settings to something else, or clean up Android Studio settings somehow?

Comment: Are you sure the "out of memory" is not a disk space issue ? On linux try "df -h" command

Answer (score 1):

What finally worked for me was downloading version 3.2 of Android Studio (if I download via Ubuntu Software it is version 3.3), installing to a different directory and reinstalling the sdk to a different directory. Not sure what part of that was the solution, but anyway, if anyway has the same problem they can try this.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to `File` then `Invalidate Caches / Restart`

Comment: It did not help. I also tried deleting the .idea directory and re-importing the project, still gets stuck on Building Symbols

Answer (score 0):

Try going to **C:\users\.android\avd** and remove all folders. If the issue is related to your emulators, deleting all folders might help.

Comment: Since I now managed to make it work, I can not check whether or not this would also solve the problem, and I am not going to touch anything on my android installation right now.